# How can I check the hit count for each rule in iptables?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I want to know how can I find out which rule was accessed and how many times, from the access list I have created using iptables.

My firewall has over 1000 input and output rules in iptbales; I want to find how many times each of them were accessed.

For example, suppose I have the following rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I want to find out how many times each of the rules 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 were hit.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`iptables` will list packet and byte counters if you specify option `-v` for *verbose*, e.g. `iptables -vL`. Likewise `iptables-save` will list all entries including the mentioned counters for each chain, but not for each table entry (on some systems `iptables-save` requires option `-c` to include counters).

Comment: i also noticed that option and executed it and thought its wrong as its not showing anythign expect rules.. strange thing is that its showing 0 packets and 0 bytes on all the rules. this servers is used as linux firewall and there are almost 20 servers behind it and everthing is workig fine, but there is no packet or byte corosponding to any INPUT or OUTPUT chain ? Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: ohh something is there now, when i looked with my eyes open `:INPUT DROP [0:0] :FORWARD ACCEPT [74684295:91842276117] :OUTPUT DROP [0:0] :LOGGING - [0:0]`

Comment: So your forward chain has a total of 74684295 packets and a total of 91842276117 bytes.

Comment: does this mean all the rules which i have written on firewall(in iptables) with INPUT and OUTPUT are useless ?
Do i have to write all these rules again for forward  because its working as gateway/firewall for a network

Comment: The manpage of `iptables` explains (for the `filter` table): `INPUT` (for packets destined  to local  sockets), `FORWARD` (for packets being routed through the box), and `OUTPUT` (for locally-generated packets). So yes, you want these rules for the FORWARD table if this box does only do forwarding and nothing else. And be aware that `iptables-save` only lists counters for chains, not for each individual table entry.

Comment: To view hits live, `watch` can highlight them in a nice way: `sudo watch -d iptables -v -L` (the `-d` makes it show the difference).

Answer (score 9):

I use the following to check on my iptables rules:

```
iptables -nvL [INPUT|FORWARD|OUTPUT|myCHAINNAME] --line-numbers | less
```

The -n speeds up the process by not doing hostname lookups

The line numbers help with deleting rules:

```
iptables -D [INPUT|FORWARD|OUTPUT|myCHAINNAME] [Rule#]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use collectds iptables module to aggregate the counters:

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Iptables